# GA4 Event processing aborted during storage

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I am trying to send and track GA4 event with below snippet. I cannot see in GA4 dashboard even in `Debug View`. I can reach the dataLayer and see the event in that array. When I debuged with Google Analytics Debugger I saw this log which is not very clear. Does anybody know how to not 'abort' process and track events?

PS: this code runs in other websites I also thought cross-domain issue but found nothing.

[image]

```
(function () {
      const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

      const myScript = document.createElement('script');

      myScript.setAttribute(
        'src',
        `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${analyticsId}`
      );
      
      myScript.onload = function () {
        
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

        function gtag() {
          
          dataLayer.push(arguments);
        }
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', analyticsId, { debug_mode: true });

        const eventMethod = window.addEventListener
          ? 'addEventListener'
          : 'attachEvent';
        const eventer = window[eventMethod];
        const messageEvent =
          eventMethod === 'attachEvent' ? 'onmessage' : 'message';
        eventer(messageEvent, (e) => {
          
          if (e.data === 'condition1') {
            gtag('event', 'event1', {
              event_category: 'event2',
              event_label: title,
              send_to: analyticsId,
            });
          } else if (e.data === 'condition2') {
            gtag('event', 'event2', {
              event_category: 'event2',
              event_label: title,
              send_to: analyticsId,
            });
          }
        });
      };

      head.insertBefore(myScript, head.children[1]);
    })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set state 'cookie_flags': 'SameSite=None;Secure' and 'cookie_update': false on config.

```
gtag('set', {
      'cookie_flags': 'SameSite=None;Secure'
    });
gtag('config', analyticsId, {
      'cookie_update': false
});
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookies-user-id#cookie_update